# Pandas select rows with value less than in 90% columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select rows where values in 90% columns are less than a specified threshold.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 15, (10, 11)), columns=list('abcdefghijk'))
```

I can select rows where the value is less than the threshold (5) for all columns using the following syntax,

```
df[(df[list('abcdefghijk')] > 5).all(axis=1)]
```

How to do this if the value for >90% columns instead of all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need:

```
a = df[(df[list('abcdefghijk')] > 5).mean(1) > .9]
```